# c# winforms gdi+ - Crop an Image to it's contents

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, gdi+, crop

I am making a paint application in GDI+ WinForms, and I have a feature I would like to add and have tried to add and I haven't found anything about it online.

I would like to take an Image (or Bitmap, doesn't really matter) and crop it down to where all the content in it is.

Let me give an example:

I have an image here [image: (Picture of Stickman white a lot of white around it)]
And it has quite a bit of white around it (Save the image to your computer to see that it has white around it.) I would like to crop the image down to just the area where the stickman is, I would like it to look like this:

.
[image: (Cropped stickman)]

(Save it to your computer and you can compare the two)

If you look at the second one, which is what I would like to produce, it has cut the image down to just the stickman!

But, of course, I've done that myself.

I've looked online a lot for a solution and couldn't find one, so I decided to try and do it myself, it didn't work.

Here's what I tried:

I have a simple form with a picture box and a button - upon clicking of the button it should crop the image down. I made the picture box's BackColor black and it to center the image so that the areas that aren't in the image anymore were black.

The image is stored in a Bitmap called `ImageToChange`.

Upon click of the button it should crop the image - so I made a function to do that which I will call from the button

This function depends on another function that I found online to crop the image:

```
public Bitmap CropImage(Image source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        Rectangle crop = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

        var bmp = new Bitmap(crop.Width, crop.Height);
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            gr.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), crop, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

The function above should just crop and image to the x, y, width and height given to it - I didn't make the code but I can see what it does.

My `CropToContent` function depends on that at the end.

So, here is the function I created to crop the image down:

```
public Bitmap CropToContent(Bitmap oldBmp)
    {
        Rectangle currentRect = new Rectangle();

        // Get a base color

        for (int y = 0; y < oldBmp.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < oldBmp.Width; x++)
            {
                if (oldBmp.GetPixel(x, y) != Color.White)
                {
                    // We need to interpret this!

                    if (!currentRect.Contains(new Point(x, y)))
                    {
                        // This will run if this is out of the current rectangle

                        if (x > (currentRect.X + currentRect.Width)) currentRect.Width += ((currentRect.X + currentRect.Width) + x);
                        if (x < (currentRect.X))
                        {
                            // Move the rectangle over there and extend it's width to make the right the same!
                            int oldRectLeft = currentRect.Left;

                            currentRect.X = x;
                            currentRect.Width += oldRectLeft - x;
                        }

                        if (y > (currentRect.Y + currentRect.Height)) currentRect.Height += ((currentRect.Y + currentRect.Height) + y);

                        if (y < (currentRect.Y + currentRect.Height))
                        {
                            int oldRectTop = currentRect.Top;

                            currentRect.Y = y;
                            currentRect.Height += oldRectTop - y;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return CropImage(oldBmp, currentRect.X, currentRect.Y, currentRect.Width, currentRect.Height);
    }
```

As you can see, it uses the `CropImage` function I mentioned earlier!

This function has a rectangle of where the image will be cropped to - this gets modified as the function goes along.

The function loops through all the pixels in the Bitmap and if it isn't white it ignores it - if it is anything else however it will do a certain depending on where around the rectangle it is,

If it's on the left of the rectangle it will move the X of the rectangle over and change the Width so the right of the rectangle is still the same

If it's on the top of the rectangle it will move the Y of the rectangle up and change the Height...

If it's on the right of the rectangle it will change the Width to match.

If it's on the bottom of the rectangle it will change the Height to match.

And if it's inside the rectangle it won't care at all.

I can't see why this function would not work.

Upon `Load` of the form it runs this code:

```
ImageToChange = Properties.Resources.stickman;

        pictureBox1.Image = ImageToChange;
```

And I put the untouched stickman into `Properties.Resources.stickman`.

Then on click of the button it runs:

```
ImageToChange = CropToContent(ImageToChange);

        pictureBox1.Image = ImageToChange;
```

I cannot see why this won't work and thank you very much if you read the whole thing.

Comment: Always start small when debugging code, this image has entirely too many pixels and you'll easily run out of patience.  Start with a 1x1 bitmap, good to check boundary condition.  Next is 3x3 with a pixel in the center.  Then one on an edge.  Then two.  By then you'll have 99% of the bugs removed.

Comment: OK, I'll try with a much smaller image then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer has finally come thanks to Hans Passant pointing out that I should step through it and keep an eye on it which a much small image.

And Robin Krom saying that some of the logic was off.

This is the end result:

```
public Bitmap CropToContent(Bitmap oldBmp)
    {
        Rectangle currentRect = new Rectangle();
        bool IsFirstOne = true;

        // Get a base color

        for (int y = 0; y < oldBmp.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < oldBmp.Width; x++)
            {
                Color debug = oldBmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (oldBmp.GetPixel(x, y) != Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255))
                {
                    // We need to interpret this!

                    // Check if it is the first one!

                    if (IsFirstOne)
                    {
                        currentRect.X = x;
                        currentRect.Y = y;
                        currentRect.Width = 1;
                        currentRect.Height = 1;
                        IsFirstOne = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        if (!currentRect.Contains(new Point(x, y)))
                        {
                            // This will run if this is out of the current rectangle

                            if (x > (currentRect.X + currentRect.Width)) currentRect.Width = x - currentRect.X;
                            if (x < (currentRect.X))
                            {
                                // Move the rectangle over there and extend it's width to make the right the same!
                                int oldRectLeft = currentRect.Left;

                                currentRect.X = x;
                                currentRect.Width += oldRectLeft - x;
                            }

                            if (y > (currentRect.Y + currentRect.Height)) currentRect.Height = y - currentRect.Y;

                            if (y < (currentRect.Y + currentRect.Height))
                            {
                                int oldRectTop = currentRect.Top;

                                currentRect.Y = y;
                                currentRect.Height += oldRectTop - y;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return CropImage(oldBmp, currentRect.X, currentRect.Y, currentRect.Width, currentRect.Height);
    }
```

I figured out when debugging with a smaller image that on the first pixel I have to set the starting point for the Rectangle - it defaults to 0, 0 and if the first pixel is at 2, 2 it will be on the right of course.

The rectangle extends one and is now at the location of 0, 0 with the width of 1... yeah... that's not correct - it needs to start where the first pixel is, so I added that.

And I of course fixed up the logic thanks to Robin Krom and the function worked perfectly on the stickman!

So it starts like this:
[image: The start]

and the result is this:

[image: The end result]

It's also worth noting that the line `if (oldBmp.GetPixel(x, y) != Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255))` used to be `if (oldBmp.GetPixel(x, y) != Color.White)` which didn't work, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit through of by the question with what you mean with "won't work", but I think I found the issue.

The error is in your logic, for instance the line of code which modifies the right side of the rectangle:

```
if (x > (currentRect.X + currentRect.Width)) currentRect.Width += ((currentRect.X + currentRect.Width) + x);
```

This modifies the width of the detected rectangle by *adding* x, rectangle.X and rectangle.Width which is wrong. What you want is probably this:

```
if (x > (currentRect.X + currentRect.Width)) currentRect.Width = x - currentRect.X;
```

You will need similar changes to the rest of your logic.

Comment: ok, I'll change the rest of the logic, it's also worth mentioning that the `if (bmp.GetPixel(x, y) == Color.White)` didn't seem to work and it should be `if (bmp.GetPixel(x, y) == Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255))` if these were the two problems I'll mark this answer as the answer.

Comment: It turns out there were three problems so I've made the actual answer.

Comment: The fact that the color comparison didn't work is that your bitmap probably has the pixelformat Format32bppArgb (or another 32 bit), and you will need to compare the alpha too. A solution for that is to get the color of the pixel from the bitmap itself.


Greenshot has an implementation which tries to get the crop region for the color of every single corner, and see which generates the biggest rectangle:
https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot/blob/master/GreenshotPlugin/Core/ImageHelper.cs#L326